# All Store Views option was missed in Magento

Tags: magento

I am working in Magento EE-1.10.1.1. In my store backend the "All Store Views" option was missed now. Last day I worked in store & store views to test something.

Can any one knows how to bring back that option in my store.

Comment: This is not a programming question, so it's probably better off on Magento's support resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permission/role for admin was changed to a single store only. Now I changed and gave full access to admin.

But this changes are done from DB.